# Own SSH key file to tie up for SSH access to a foreign Linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, key, ssh-keys

We are to have SSH access to client's Linux server for code installation and launch. As the client has given us FTP connection
client has also said:
"SSH access: Can you **send me your SSH key**. I will **connect it to our Linux server**."

**Is this procedure correct, valid ?**

Seems to me client should generate SSH key and forward to us for SSH access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate a public/private keypair (e.g. using `ssh-keygen -r` for an RSA-key). Share the public key with the customer (the name "public" indicates it is ok to share. The customer will add the public key to the server's `authorized_keys` file, so the owner of the corresponding private key (that is you) can login.

What you are suggesting is wrong, as the client should not send you the private key of a key-pair. As the name indicates, private keys should never be shared.